# Induced map on $K_{1}$-group

Tags: c-star-algebras, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory, k-theory

Let $A$ be a unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Any automorphism $\alpha$ of $A$ induces a map on $K_{1}(A)$ by $\alpha_{\ast}[u]=[\alpha(u)]$.

Let the automorphism $\alpha$ be inner, does it follow that $\alpha_{\ast}$ is the identity map?

I guess the answer is negative because unitary equivalence is far from homotopy of unitaries. The answer may also depend on the type of the $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you add some linebreaks.

Comment: Crossposted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132283/inner-automorphisms-and-k-theory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short:** this is essentially because $K_1(A)$ is Abelian, and it is true for every inner automorphism of every $C^*$-algebra. But if one wants to be careful, there are a few things to check and recall. I will assume like you that $A$ is unitary, but that's true in general with the same proof, replacing $A$ by $\widetilde{A}$.

**1) Preliminary facts:** let us denote $(K_1(A),+)$. This is an Abelian group for any $C^*$-algebra $A$ and by the standard picture, we have $K_1(A)=\{[u]\,;\,u\in U_\infty(A)\}$.

> For every $v,w$ in the same $U_n(A)$, we have
>   $$
> [vw]=[wv]=[v]+[w].
> $$

That's a direct consequence of **Whitehead's lemma**. Precisely
$$
\pmatrix{u&0\\0&v}=\pmatrix{u&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{v&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\sim_h \pmatrix{uv&0\\0&1}
$$
where the rhs homotopy follows from the continuous $2\times 2$ unitary path
$$
\pmatrix{\cos t&\sin t\\ \sin t&-\cos t }.
$$
And conjugation by the same path on the lhs allows to exchange $u$ and $v$, whence the result.

In particular, for every unitary $u_n$ in $U_n(A)$, we have
$$
0=[1_n]=[u_nu_n^*]=[u_n]+[u_n^*].
$$

**Note:** with the fact above, it is easy to deduce that $K_1(A)$ is indeed Abelian. With $u\in U_n(A)$ and $v\in U_m(A)$, we can assume $m=n$ up to adding some $1$'s down the diagonal. Then $[u]+[v]=[u\oplus v]=[(uv)\oplus 1]=[(vu)\oplus 1]=[v\oplus u]=[v]+[u]$.

**2) Proof:** now assume $\alpha$ is an inner automorphism of $A$, that is there exists $u$ unitary in $A$ such that $\alpha(x)=uxu^*$ for every $x\in A$. Let us compute $\alpha_\ast=K_1(\alpha)$ on $K_1(A)$, that is on $[v]$ for every $v\in U_n(A)$, for every $n\geq 1$.

> The key point is that for $v=(v_{ij})\in U_n(A)$, still denoting by $\alpha$ the $*$-homomorphism induced by $\alpha$ on $M_n(A)$, we have
>   $$
> \alpha(v)=\pmatrix{\alpha(v_{ij})}=\pmatrix{uv_{ij}u^*}=\mbox{diag}(u,\ldots,u)\,v\,\mbox{diag}(u^*,\ldots,u^*)=u_nvu_n^*
> $$
>   where $u_n$ is the unitary of $U_n(A)$ made of a constant diagonal of $u$, and zero elsewhere.

Therefore
$$
\alpha_\ast([v])=[\alpha(v)]=[u_nvu_n^*]=[u_n]+[v]+[u_n^*]=[v]+[u_n]+[u_n^*]=[v].
$$
Thus $\alpha_\ast=K_1(\alpha)$ is the identity on $K_1(A)$.

Of course, it suffices to use the property $[vw]=[wv]$ for $v,w\in U_n(A)$ to get $[u_nvu_n^*]=[u_n^*u_nv]=[v]$. But it was a good opportunity to recall that for a unitary $u_n\in U_n(A)$, $-[u_n]=[u_n^*]$.

**3) Extension:** more generally, for every **approximately inner automorphism** of $A$, we have $K_0(\alpha)=\mbox{id}$ and $K_1(\alpha)=\mbox{id}$.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. Because of the many edits, it was converted into Community Wiki mode. If you want the moderators to undo this, so that you get "rewarded" for your work, you can flag it. See the meta thread [Automatic Community-wikification of very long answers with lots of edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1770).

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your comment, Martin.

Answer (score 2):

If I may add a little to the above answer, $K_1(A)$ is by definition the group of homotopy classes of unitaries in the unitization  $(K \otimes A)^{\sim}$ of its stabilization $K \otimes A$ (replace $A$ by $A^{\sim}$ in the non-unital case as julien stated above.)

Polar decomposition shows that every unitary in $(K \otimes A)^{\sim}$ is homotopic to one of the form $u \oplus  (1 - 1_{M_n(A)} ) $ where $u \in M_n(A)$.

Also, for any unitary $u$ in a corner $p (K \otimes A)^{\sim} p$ and for any partial isometry $s$ with $s^*s = p$, $u \oplus (1-p)$ is homotopic to $sus^* \oplus (1-ss^*)$.

So every $K_1$ class can be represented by some unitary $u \in M_n(A)$ after adding $1$'s down the diagonal and you can move a unitary $u \in M_n(A)$ up and down the diagonal without changing its $K_1$-class. It is immediate that $K_1$ is abelian and inner-automorphisms descend to the identity map on $K_1$.